# Using Datejs - Get the day of the week

Tags: javascript, date, datejs

I'm using http://www.datejs.com/. 
I must be missing it, but is there a way I can pass it the day/month/year and have it tell me that it's a Friday or Monday or whatever?

Answer (score 4):

You want:

`.toString("dddd");`

For example:

```
> Date.parse("1.16.2012").toString("dddd");
"Monday"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether it is a particular day of the week, you could do this:

`Date.parse("1.16.2012").is().monday()`