# Datejs: get the day number of the week

Tags: javascript

[Using Datejs - Get the day of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889339/using-datejs-get-the-day-of-the-week)

I'm also using http://www.datejs.com. And I also must be missing it. Is there a way I can have the **day number** of the week?

I know I can use an array equivalence, but the library is so good that I think I'm missing it, and I looked everywhere.

**UPDATE:**

I also know I can use the date getDay method, but I think there is a datejs alternative to correct some weird behavior of the built in date object.

Comment: I think you just use getDay, datejs extends the Date prototype but the original functionality of it should work fine still.

Comment: But datejs exists to correct the original date object bugs, so I think there is a alternative to the getDay method.

Comment: @lolol Date.js exists primarily to *extend* the original `Date` object, adding commonly-desired methods that aren't standardized -- such as customized formatting. There's not much to "*fix*" in `Date` objects. And Date.js itself [uses `getDay()`](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/trunk/src/core.js#837) (lines 837-840).

Comment: Of course it does, but datejs also correct weird behaivour and bugs, I don't really know what comes primarily, or none of then does, but I think it is there to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number with the standard `Date` methods, [`getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) or [`getUTCday`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDay):

```
new Date('2012-10-03').getDay(); // 2
```

Comment: @lolol `getDay` is a [standardized method](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.16) of `Date` objects. What "*weird behavior*" are you expecting from it for Date.js to fix?

Comment: I don't know. Is there any? I moved to datejs to avoid researching workarounds for every built in date object bug or weird behaviour. But don't you think datejs should have a particular method for this, even if it doesn't do nothing than call getDay?

Comment: @lolol `Date` objects really aren't that broken. Where you might find compatibility issues are with support for recent additions, such as [formatting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) and parsing [ISO 8601 date strings](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Answer (score 1):

just use the built in [`getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) function on the `Date` object:

```
new Date().getDay();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code calculates the day of the week for dates after 1700/1/1 through one of the algorithms that exist to calculate it

```
var weekDay = function(year, month, day) {
                  var offset = [0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334];
                  var week   = {0:'Sunday', 
                                1:'Monday', 
                                2:'Tuesday', 
                                3:'Wednesday', 
                                4:'Thursday', 
                                5:'Friday', 
                                6:'Saturday'};
                  var afterFeb = (month > 2)? 0 : 1;
                  aux = year - 1700 - afterFeb;
                  // dayOfWeek for 1700/1/1 = 5, Friday
                  dayOfWeek  = 5;                      
                  // partial sum of days betweem current date and 1700/1/1
                  dayOfWeek += (aux + afterFeb) * 365;
                  // leap year correction
                  dayOfWeek += parseInt(aux / 4) - 
                               parseInt(aux / 100) + 
                               parseInt((aux + 100) / 400);
                  // sum monthly and day offsets
                  dayOfWeek += offset[month - 1] + (day - 1);
                  dayOfWeek = parseInt(dayOfWeek % 7);

                  return [dayOfWeek, week[dayOfWeek]];
              };  


console.log(weekDay(2013, 6, 15)[0] == 6, weekDay(2013, 6, 15)[1] == "Saturday");
console.log(weekDay(1969, 7, 20)[0] == 0, weekDay(1969, 7, 20)[1] == "Sunday");
console.log(weekDay(1945, 4, 30)[0] == 1, weekDay(1945, 4, 30)[1] == "Monday");
console.log(weekDay(1900, 1, 1)[0]  == 1,  weekDay(1900, 1, 1)[1] == "Monday");
console.log(weekDay(1789, 7, 14)[0] == 2, weekDay(1789, 7, 14)[1] == "Tuesday");
```